# Issues installing RVM on Manjaro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, archlinux, manjaro

I follow the steps on the Arch Wiki, but after I follow the single-user installation steps, RVM does nothing and I get an error when opening up my terminal.
The error is `/home/keifer/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file`

Comment: I only get output when I put `source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` in my .bashrc
When I put `$ [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` in my .bashrc, nothing is outputted.

Comment: You should not add the `$` character from the beginning into your `.bashrc`. This seems like a typo in the Arch Wiki.

Comment: The `$` is not a typo, it represents the terminal prompt and it should not be copied, putting only `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` should work just fine. Have you tried checking [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RVM#Post_Installation)? If you get a faulty output check if you have installed `rvm` for your user, if not, then try installing without `sudo` and get back here with more info.

Comment: I added `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` to my .bash_profile and then executed the command in my terminal. 
I am left with `type: rvm: not found` when executing `type rvm | head -n1`

Comment: Sourced my bash profile, but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Did you do the multi-user or single user install? Do you have a script in `.rvm/scripts/rvm` at all?

Comment: @Casper I followed single user install and there is no script folder in `~\.rvm`

Comment: Did you run `curl -L get.rvm.io > rvm-install` and then `bash < ./rvm-install`? Again without the dollar signs. Did you look at the `rvm-install` script at all to check if it does exist and that it contains something? If not please double check, because it seems for some reason those two commands did not execute properly.

Comment: rvm-install appeared to be successful, and I added my user to the rvm group, but I have nothing in scripts folder still.